# Exclude categories from wp query not working

Tags: theme-development

Im using this code to exclude a category but it still show all posts in exhibition.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'exhibition',
    'taxonomy' => 'categories_for_exhibitions',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array('current'),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
));
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer so it can benefit someone else

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'exhibition',
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'categories_for_exhibitions',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'current',
                operator => 'NOT IN',
            ),
        )

));
```